# Fundamental Group Contains Infinite Cyclic Subgroup

Tags: algebraic-topology, cyclic-groups, fundamental-groups

> Let $X \subseteq \Bbb{R}^2$ s.t. $\Bbb{R}^2$ such that $S^1 \subseteq X \subseteq \Bbb{R}^2 - \{(0,0)\}$. Prove that contains $\pi_1(X,(0,1))$ an infinite cyclic subgroup.

Here's what I did. Let $j : S^1 \to X$ be the embedding of $S^1$ into $X$. I then showed that the induced homomorphism $j_* : \pi_1(S^1,(0,1)) \to \pi_1(X, (0,1))$ injective, so $\pi_1(X,(0,1))$ contains the subgroup $j_*(\pi_1(S^1,(0,1))) \simeq \pi_1(S^1,(0,1)) \simeq \Bbb{Z}$. However, I didn't really use the fact that $X \subseteq \Bbb{R}^2 - \{(0,0)\}$ in my proof, which makes me nervous. Does what I did sound right? Here's my proof of injectivity.

> Let $\alpha$ be a loop $(0,1)$ such that $j_*([\alpha]) = [1_{(0,1)}]$ (note that $1_{(0,1)}$ is the constant loop about $(0,1)$, not the indicator function). Then $[j \circ \alpha] = [1_{(0,1)}]$ which implies there is some path homotopy $H : I \times I \to X$ such that $H(s,0) = j(\alpha (s)) = \alpha (s)$ and $H(s,1) = 1_{(0,1)}(s) = (0,1)$ for every $s \in I$; and $H(0,t) = (0,1) = H(1,t)$ for every $t \in I$. But these are points in $S^1$, so the codomain of $H$ can be restricted and this gives a path homotopy between $\alpha$ and $1_{(0,1)}$ itself.

...As I'm typing this up, I now see the issue. The "boundaries" of the map lie in $S^1$, but there is no guarantee that what is happening "in between" stays in $S^1$...I think I could use a hint at this point. The fact that we are subtracting an interior point of $S^1$ from $\Bbb{R}^2$ should play some role.

Comment: You found the mistake in your proof; I added a hint to help you solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** there is $r: \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\} \to S^1$ such that $S^1\to \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}\to S^1$ is the identity on $S^1$; and $S^1\to X\to \mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{0\} = S^1\to X\to \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$

Comment: In other words, $S^1$ is a retract of $X$.